# What is the time complexity in accessing any element arbitrarily in different data structures?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I just want to know the run time complexity in Big-O notation of accessing an element arbitrarily using Array, singly-linked list without a tail pointer, and using doubly linked list with a tail pointer.

Comment: Hi @Zilan, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please using Internet to learn and find it. If you find an issue in finding complexity of something so there we can help. your question should show some research.

Answer (score 0):

It will be O(1) for Arrays and O(n) for other lists where 'n' is the size of lists

Comment: This is not true for arrays when accessing elements by index.